# Prolog - Substitute atom with value and evaluate

Tags: prolog

Given

```
Result = 4* (3*x)^3*3,
```

and

```
VarValue = x:2,
```

How can I get the following output

```
Value = 2592 ;
```

if I have to defined the following predicate:

```
evaluate(Result,Value,VarValue)
```

I tried doing the following:

```
evaluate(Result, Value, VarValue) :- member(VarValue, [x:X]).
```

and trying to substitute X into the equation.. I could not think of a nice way to go from there.

EDIT: Is there a way to only use the following built-predicates :

```
 //, /, +, -, ^, *,=..,>, <,
 atom, is_list, functor, arg, integer, number, member, append
```

Comment: You really should show some work toward this. Did you try anything st all?

Comment: @mbratch It's in the edit. I tried making a clean solution but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think joel76 solution can be made a bit more compact:

```
exp_symbols(Symbols, Expr, WithSym) :-
    Expr =.. [F|Args],
    ( memberchk(F:V, Symbols) -> G = V ; G = F ),
    maplist(exp_symbols(Symbols), Args, ArgsSWithSym),
    WithSym =.. [G|ArgsSWithSym].

evaluate(Exp, LstVars, Val) :-
    exp_symbols(LstVars, Exp, NewExp),
    Val is NewExp.
```

Comment: Any idea as to how to only use the following predicates: //, /, +, -, ^, *,=..,>, <, atom, is_list, functor, arg, integer, number, member, append. I know I can use member instead of memberchk but what is an alternative to maplist?

Comment: maplist it's very simple, just [apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply) the first argument (a predicate) to each lists' elements: `maplist(F,[E|Es],[M|Ms]) :- call(F,E,M), maplist(F,Es,Ms). maplist(_,[],[]).`

Comment: I was thinking of using the univ operator (=..) to extract info. What do you think?

Comment: in maplist ? doesn't make sense.

Comment: Instead of maplist. Like using (=..) to extract ops, left and right part and then recursively evaluating left and right. Then I would use =.. again to calculate result.

Comment: @CapelliC Would you be able to break down what each line in the exp_symbols clause is doing. I'm working on a similar problem here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143072/prolog-evaluator-that-uses-previously-solved-information-as-input).

Answer (score 1):

You can use =.. :

```
evaluate(Exp, LstVars, Val) :-
    analyse(LstVars, Exp, NewExp),
    Val is NewExp.


analyse(LstVars, Term,R) :-
    functor(Term, Term, 0), !,
    (   member(Term : V, LstVars)
    ->  R = V
    ;   R = Term).

analyse(LstVars, Term, V) :-
    functor(Term, Name, _),
    Term =.. [Name | Lst],
    maplist(analyse(LstVars), Lst, LstV),
    V =.. [Name|LstV].
```

For example :

```
?- evaluate(4* (3*x)^3*y, [x:2, y:(-3)], L). 
L = -2592.

?- evaluate(4* (3*x)^3*3, [x:2], L). 
L = 2592.
```

**EDIT** I remove **member(Term:(V), LstVars) -> R = (V)** wich is useless.

Comment: Nice solution! But is there a way to use the following predicates: //, /, +, -, ^, *,=..,>, <,
 atom, is_list, functor, arg, integer, number, member, append

Comment: @David `maplist`is the only outlier in joel76's solution, and easy to implement yourself as an auxiliary predicate for this application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started. It supports only addition and subtraction, and no braces. Adding more operations is trivial, adding braces support is more tricky.

```
evaluate(X, X, _) :- number(X).
evaluate(Var, Val, Var:Val).
evaluate(A-B, Val, VarVal) :-
    evaluate(A, Aval, VarVal),
    evaluate(B, Bval, VarVal),
    Val is Aval - Bval.
evaluate(A+B, Val, VarVal) :-
    evaluate(A, Aval, VarVal),
    evaluate(B, Bval, VarVal),
    Val is Aval + Bval.
```

Let's try it:

```
?- evaluate(2+2, Result, x:10).
Result = 4 

?- evaluate(2+x, Result, x:10).
Result = 12 

?- evaluate(2+x-34+x, Result, x:10).
Result = -12
```