# Prolog evaluator that uses previously solved information as input

Tags: compilation, prolog, evaluator

I have written a program that takes a parse tree as input and evaluates it. It works when the identifiers in the tree do not reoccur.
I want the evaluator to take in multiple statements, and use the values assigned to identfiers when I solve later statements. Here is my program.

```
add_op --> ['+'].
assign_op --> ['='].
ident(ident(Ident)) --> [Ident], {atom(Ident)}. /* True if an identifier */
int(int(Int)) --> [Int], {integer(Int)}. /* True if an integer */
semicolon --> [';'].

evaluator(statements(Assignment),VariablesOut):-
    evaluator(Assignment,VariablesOut).

evaluator(statements(Assignment,Statements),VariablesOut):-
    evaluator(Assignment,List1),
    evaluator(Statements,List2),
    merge(List1,List2,VariablesOut).

evaluator(assignment(ident(Ident),assign_op,int(Int),add_op,int(Int2),semicolon),Answer5):-
    Answer2 is Int + Int2,
    atom_concat(Ident,' = ',Answer1),
    atom_concat(Answer1,Answer2,Answer3),
    read_term_from_atom(Answer3, (Answer4), []),    /*removes quotation marks*/
    Answer5 = [Answer4].
```

The following execution uses a parse tree for a = 2 + 3 ; b = 3 + 4 ;
This execution works because my program is only evaluating the answers to a and b, and the evaluation of b does not contain a.

```
evaluator(statements(assignment(ident(a), assign_op, int(2), add_op, int(3), semicolon), statements(assignment(ident(b), assign_op, int(3), add_op, int(4), semicolon))), Answer).
Answer = [a=5, b=7].
```

The following uses a parse tree for a = 2 + 3 ; b = a + 4 ;
This one does not work, because b must be the result of 4 added to a, and a is not assigned to the value 5 within the program.

```
evaluator(statements(assignment(ident(a), assign_op, int(2), add_op, int(3), semicolon), statements(assignment(ident(b), assign_op, int(a), add_op, int(4), semicolon))), Answer).

ERROR: Arithmetic: `a/0' is not a function
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] _2952 is a+4
...
```

**Update**

I found a similar [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124644/prolog-substitute-atom-with-value-and-evaluate), but I'm not sure exactly how it works. I don't know where any evaluation is happening and I don't see how the maplist and WithSym =.. lines are needed.

```
exp_symbols(Symbols, Expr, WithSym) :-
    Expr =.. [F|Args],   /*F is sent to the first element of Expr which in my case would be a = 5 */
    ( member(F=V, Symbols) -> G = V ; G = F ), /* if F followed by a colon and some element V is in the equation, set G to be assign to both V and F */
    maplist(exp_symbols(Symbols), Args, ArgsSWithSym), /*perform the current function on all elements left **/
    WithSym =.. [G|ArgsSWithSym]. /** Set WithSym to be the first element in ArgsSWithSym /**

evaluate(Exp, LstVars, Val) :-
    exp_symbols(LstVars, Exp, NewExp),
    Val is NewExp.
```

Comment: When writing an interpreter such as this, you need to keep track of any evaluated variables between each statement execution and do the variable value substitutions before attempting the next statement evaluation. Prolog (or any other language you would use to do this task) has no idea that `a` represents a variable that has a value from the prior statement. That's something you have to manage yourself. It's in your interpreter's world, not in Prolog's world.

Comment: Yes I know this, I'm hoping someone can give me some insight on how to do this.

Comment: This is a simple language interpreter which isn't totally trivial even in this simple case. You should do some reading on strategies for implementing them. Your code is combining parsing with semantics and evaluation. As you evaluate each statement, starting from the first one, you need to maintain a dictionary of symbols with their associated computed values. As you do the next statement, you have to substitute any values determined so far from that dictionary before attempting to evaluate that statement. The dictionary can be key-value pairs in Prolog. There are other options as well.

Comment: @lurker Do you know any helpful links?

Comment: @Tomas Are you referring to something like this? My best attempt is to add in `b_setval(Answer2,Ident)` right above `Answer5 = [Answer4].` but that doesn't appear to fix the problem.

Comment: @TomasBy Could you be more specific? I'm not sure exactly what you mean by prolog variables and prolog vars. This is what I can find on Prolog Variables(https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Variables) and when you say "replace them with Prolog vars" it looks like your saying Prolog vars are something different perhaps? But I can't find anything on just prolog vars online or in the reading material I have.

Comment: In your question, it looks like you are calling exactly the same `evaluator` query in both the working and non-working cases. Please edit your question and fix the second query to be what you entered when you got the error. I would think in the second case that `assignment(ident(b), assign_op, int(3), add_op, int(4), semicolon)` would really be `assignment(ident(b), assign_op, ident(a), add_op, int(4), semicolon)`, in which case you don't have an `evaluator` predicate clause that matches.

Comment: @lurker Sorry, I thought I had checked for that. I fixed it now.

Comment: One big problem is `int(a)`. That's simply invalid. `a` is an identifier, not an `int` and needs to be treated as `ident(a)`, which your predicate currently doesn't handle. At the point where it needs a value, you need a table to look up the previously determined value or, as Tomas is saying, use Prolog variables to do this for you. I'm not saying much new here beyond my prior comments.

Comment: I've been looking up how to make a table. It looks like this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124644/prolog-substitute-atom-with-value-and-evaluate) is doing something really similar, but I'm not really sure which parts I need to extrapolate from the main answer

Comment: Prolog uses lists. As I mentioned in a prior comment already, you could use key-value pairs (in a list). Or lists of terms such as `(variable, value)`. The example you linked uses lists of `variable:value`. Lots of ways to do it. But it would be a list overall.

Comment: Yes in the solution I found it looks like they are using lists. I posted the part of that solution as an update to this question with some comments because the solution there is confusing to me.

Comment: Evaluation is happening in this statement: `Val is NewExp`. The `is/2` operator evaluates arithmetic expressions. Before it can, though, all variables must be resolved to a value. If you have a Prolog variable `X` and its instantiated as `(3 + 5) / 2` then `Exp is X` will evaluate `(3 + 5) / 2` and give you `Exp = 4`. Or more generally, if you have Prolog variables `X = 3` and `Y = 5` and you have `Z = (X + Y)/2` then `Exp is Z` will result in `Exp = 4`.

Comment: The `maplist` line handles recursion of the expression. The linked problem handles layers of nested expressions, such as `(3 + 4*(5-2*3))`. If the `=..` is confusing, then use the 2nd answer instead, which is spelled out more.

Comment: I redid my code and now have to solve a smaller problem. I moved the question to this page(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156852/replacing-atom-with-corresponding-value-from-a-list-in-prolog)