# Replacing atom with corresponding value from a list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have the following code. I pass in an atom as the first argument a list of equalities as the second argument, and I want to return the value of the atom according to the list of equalities.

```
evaluator(Id,VariablesIn,Answer):-
     exp_symbols(Id,VariablesIn,Answer).

exp_symbols(Id, VariablesIn, VariablesOut) :-
     VariablesIn =.. [F|Args],   
     ( member(F=V, Id) -> G = V ; G = F ), 
     maplist(exp_symbols(Id), Args, ArgsSWithSym),
     VariablesOut =.. [G|ArgsSWithSym].
```

When I call

```
evaluator(a,[a=2,b=3],Answer).
```

I want this to return

```
Answer = 2
```

Because my list species that a=2

Instead I get

```
Answer = [a=2, b=3].
```

Comment: @lurker Could you reword that comment, I'm not sure what you are saying.

Comment: Thank-you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! If you post that first comment as an answer I mark it the correct one.

Comment: You're just calling the `evaluator` incorrectly. Try `evaluator([a=2,b=3], a, Answer).`

Comment: What you had before worked for me, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: See the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest case, if you're just looking up one variable in your mapping:

```
lookup(Variable, Mapping, Value) :- member(Variable=Value, Mapping).
```

This gives you a trivial lookup:

```
| ?- lookup(a, [a=1,b=2], Value).

Value = 1

yes
| ?-
```

If you want to do an expression, you'll need to do something more elaborate, which is where `=../2` comes into play. For example, if you have `a+3`, that is equivalent to `'+'(a, 3)`. You need to pull out the arguments and apply the mapping to the ones that are not numbers. Since expressions can be embedded (*e.g.*, `a*(b + (4*c))`), that means it must be recursive. `=../2` will associate a term with a list where the head is the functor and the rest of the list (the tail) are the arguments. For example, `foo(a, b) =.. [F | Args]` results in `F = foo` and `Args = [a, b]`. So, `'+'(a, 3) =.. [F | Args]` results in `F = '+'` and `Args = [a, 3]`.

The code you posted actually does work using the method I just described, you just called it incorrectly. You called, `evaluator(a, [a=2,b=3], Answer)` but you should have called `evaluator([a=2,b=3], a, Answer)`:

```
| ?- evaluator([a=2,b=3], a, Answer).

Answer = 2

yes
| ?-
```

And for more complex expressions:

```
| ?- evaluator([a=2,b=3], (a+3)*(b+7), Answer).

Answer = (2+3)*(3+7)

yes
| ?-
```

Again, these results are directly from the code that you posted in your question.